# Linear Algebra, Subspaces and Basis Properties

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Let $w = (1, 1 ,2, -1), W = \{ u \in\Bbb R^4\mid u \cdot w = 2 \}$, and

$V = \{ u - (1, 0, 1, 1)\mid u \in W \}$.

(a) Is $W$ a subspace? Explain your answer

(b) Show that $V$ is a subspace and that $T = \{ (-1, 1, 0, 0) , (-2, 0, 1, 0) , (1, 0, 0, 1) \}$ is a basis for $V$.

(c) Let $T$ be the basis of $V$ defined in (b)

Find $[(4, -1, 1, 5)]_T$. Show your workings, however, you do not need to show your elementary row operations.

So I have shown part (a) but I'm somewhat confused about part (b) and (c), I have attached a link for better referencing and my workings there, for the question https://ibb.co/wp0RcnC
my working is https://ibb.co/qgzBDg3

Thanks in advance to whoever that could help me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). And Please [don’t use 
images](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem) instead of typing your working.

Comment: I have changed your notation to LaTeX to make it more readable. Please write future questions using LaTeX since that will make your question a lot easier to read/understand. If you are not familiar there are many great resources to learn LaTeX online!

Comment: "I'm somewhat confused about part (b) and (c)," needs more focus.

Answer (score 1):

For b) notice that $V$ is 3-dimensional since it is a rotation of the normal space associated to the 1-dimensional subspace $\langle(1,1,2,-1)\rangle$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Therefore it suffice to check that the three vectors are linearly independent and elements of $V$ to prove that they form a basis. I'll check that $(−1,1,0,0)\in V$ you can check the other two analogously.
For $(−1,1,0,0)\in V$ to be true we need to have $\left((−1,1,0,0)+(1,0,1,1)\right)\cdot w =2$ i.e.
\begin{align}
(0,1,1,1)\cdot (1,1,2,-1) = 0 + 1 + 2 -1=2
\end{align}
. Therefore $(−1,1,0,0)\in V$ is true. Checking that these are linearly independent is straightforward using any method to solve the linear system of equations you like. Unfortunatly I am not familiar with the notation you used for c) if you could explain that I can try to answer that too.

Comment: Can i ask why was the notation changed from u - (1 0 1 1) to u + (1 0 1 1), is it because the vectors in T are the final result of u - (1 0 1 1) and therefore to get u the notation is changed to u + (1 0 1 1). So I just have to prove that these three vectors in T exists in V while fulfilling the criteria that u . w = 2. Apologies I didnt knew this method of proving existed, I was taught in school that to prove a basis, one has to be linearly independent and span(T) = V. which meant I write down span of (T) and span of (V) side by side and rref them to check for consistency and vise versa.

Comment: For (b) To prove that V is a subspace, the first property of having an origin is proven as u = (1 0 1 1) for origin to exist and that also fulfils the u . w = 2 as well. but how do I go about showing the closed under addition and closed under scalar multiplication part ? Thanks for the insights

Comment: The aim is to check that the vectors $t_i$ of $T$ are in $V$, that is they are of the form $u_i-(1,0,1,1)$ for some $u_i\in W$. This means that $u_i=t_i+(1,0,1,1)$ is in $W$. It is what is checked.

Answer (score 1):

On $c),$ you get the system:

$$\begin {pmatrix} -1&-2&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end {pmatrix}\begin {pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end {pmatrix}=\begin {pmatrix}4\\-1\\1\\5\end {pmatrix}.$$

Then $(a,b,c)=[(4,-1,1,5)]_T.$

There is a solution and it's $(-1,1,5).$

Comment: I forgot to mention that I got it, but thanks for your input anyways appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**(b)** The answer of Womm is correct. I'll just expand a little bit. You seem to know that to prove that a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$, it is sufficient to prove that the subset is closed under addition and closed under multiplication with a scalar.

I will denote $a$ the vector $(1,0,1,1)$ and notice that $a \cdot w = 2$.

**Closed under addition.** What you want to prove is the following: assume that $v^1$ and $v^2$ are in $V$, then $v^1 + v^2$ is in $V$. Or said with the definition of $V$, you want to prove the following: assume that $v^1\in V$ and $v^2\in V$, then there exists $u\in W$ such that
$$
  v^1 + v^2 = u - a \ .
$$
I will now construct $u$ to prove that this is indeed true.

Assume that $v^1\in V$ and $v^2\in V$. Since $v^1\in V$, there exists $u^1\in W$ such that $v^1 = u^1 - a$. In the same way, there exists $u^2\in W$ such that $v^2 = u^2 - a$. I construct
$$
  u = v^1 + v^2 + a = u^1 + u^2 - a \ .
$$
Now $u \cdot w = u^1\cdot w + u^2\cdot w - a\cdot w = 2 + 2 -2=2$ which show that $u\in W$. Moreover $u-a=v^1+v^2$ by construction. (Remark: note that there is only one way to construct $u$ such that $v^1+v^2=u-a$. It is what I used to construct $u$.)

**Closed under multiplication with a scalar.** What you want to prove is the following: assume that $v^1$ is in $V$ and $\alpha$ a real, then $\alpha v^1$ is in $V$. Reformulating with the definition of $V$, you want to prove the following: assume that $v^1\in V$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, then there exists $u\in W$ such that $\alpha v^1=u-a$. The proof is also performed by contruction of $u$.

Do the ''same'' as above and use the only possible way to construct $u$. Then check that $u$ has indeed to desired properties.

**Remark.** In the proofs above, the only property used on $a$ is that $a\cdot w=2$, that is $a\in W$. This suggests that if I define
$$
  V' = \{u−b | u∈W\}
$$
for some $b\in W$, then $V'=V$.

**$T$ is a basis of $V$.** Since $V$ is a (finite dimensional) subspace, it has a dimension. First, show that the dimension of $V$ is at most 3: to do this, choose carefully a vector and show that it is not in $V$. Second, show that the dimension is at least 3: to do this, show that the 3 vectors of $T$ are in $V$ and are linearly indepedent. The dimension is thus 3. But then $T$ must be a basis of $V$.

**(c)** Just write down properly what it means to find the coordinates of a vector in a basis. In your case, you should be able to (really easily) solve the system of linear equations.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion but I wanted to know since there is only one solution of u for u . w = 2 to exist and that u is [1 0 1 1], if u^1 or u^2 was used, would that change the parameters of u and cause the u . w = 2 to be invalid as only [1 0 1 1] is the solution.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean. I guess you are talking about the "closed under addition" part. But anyway, what makes you think that the constructed $u$ is $(1,0,1,1)$?